# вывод всех элементов первого списка, которых нет во втором списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, python-2.x

Пользователь вводит 2 слова. Каждая буква первого слова добавляется в массив1. Аналогично -- для слова 2 и массива2.

Требуется вывести буквы первого массива, которых нет во втором массиве.

```
text1 = str(input("\nВведите первое слово >> "))
text2 = str(input("Введите второе слово >> "))

text1_list = list(text1)
text2_list = list(text2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text1 = set(input("\nВведите первое слово >> "))
text2 = input("Введите второе слово >> ")
print(text1.difference(text2))
```